# Problem by $output and permalinks

Tags: permalinks

I have a problem by `$output` in a plugin in My custom Template, I do it this:

```
$output .= "<h2><a href='".the_permalink()."' title='" .printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) )"' rel="bookmark">'".php the_title()."'></a></h2>";
```

But the link doesn't work it return just the normal text and not the link to the post, can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

The template tags [`the_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink) and [`the_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) do not return values, they echo them.
Use [`get_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_permalink) and [`get_the_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/get_the_title) instead.

As an aside, the earlier are simply wrappers that echo the return of the latter.
As another aside, yes, the naming is inconsistent.
(And yes, that's annoying. At least to me.)

Comment: Tnk for yuor answer, I change it but now it reports a problem on the line and doesen't works, Can U write a complete line please?

Comment: Ok now it work I do it this:  $output .= "<h2><a href='".get_permalink()."'>".get_the_title()."</a></h2>"; tnk a lot!!